# Best way to kill an out of process dll ('dllhost.exe' 'COM Surrogate') when an App exits?

Tags: c#, process, com, com+

I am using the 'DllSurrogate' method to allow a 64-bit C# exe to talk to a 32-bit C# dll.
The method is described in [Hosting a .NET DLL as an Out-Of-Process COM Server (EXE)](https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-net-dll-out-process).

When the App runs an extra process called 'dllhost.exe *32' automatically shows up in Task Manager, with the description 'COM Surrogate'.
This is the link between the App and the 32-bit dll.

The problem I have is that this process is not killed when the App exits.
Can someone suggest the recommended way of dealing with this?

I could find the process and kill it as my App closes, but I would need to make sure:

- It is my 'COM Surrogate', not one belonging to another App.
- It is not being used by another running instance of my App.

Is there a more direct link between my App and this process that I can check?

Comment: It's much easier to use Windows' Component Services (a.k.a "com+ applications", which relies on the same surrogate technology). You'll have access to cool UI dialogs that allow you to do many things, including defining how you want it to shutdown

Comment: Really?  When I looked into it recently I think I read the opposite, that COM+ was quite hard work and this approach was a lot more straightforward.  Does it make any difference that this is a standalone windows application, downloaded and installed by external customers?

Comment: It's really the same thing for 15+ years. "COM+" is (was) just a fancy (really?) marketing name. Component Services is the UI above it. Of course, down the road, it also uses dllhost.exe (in the out-of-process case, which is named "server" mode as opposed to "library" mode, aka in-process). You even have scripting support if you want to install all this programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A COM surrogate, which refuses to terminate, usually indicates outstanding references to a `CoClass` or resources, which haven't been released yet. You can enforce the release by resorting to [`ReleaseComObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FinalReleaseComObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx). However, when using this approach, you should be aware of the associated risks, as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous/).

If you're still seeing no other way than terminating the COM surrogate manually, you'll need to enumerate all `dllhost.exe` processes on your machine. Extract the command line of each candidate and look for the `/ProcessId` argument. If it matches the `GUID` of your `CoClass`, then you have found the match.

Comment: So you are saying that the COM surrogate should terminate automatically, even though it is out of process for the App that is actually closed?

Comment: Yes, that's how surrogates work. As soon as the reference count reaches zero and all resources are released, the process terminates, since it's no longer required.

Comment: That's encouraging.  I will look into what might be keeping the reference then, thanks.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work. I call 'Marshal.ReleaseComObject' and it returns 0 but the COM Surrogate is still left open. Could it be because I am having to create the COM object using 'CoCreateInstance', rather than an RCW?  Is there something similar I need to do instead or as well?

Comment: `CoCreateInstance` is meant to be used from C++, not C#. Are you p/invoking it? Maybe you could update your question with more details. Regarding the surrogate: do you have any unmanaged resources in your `CoClass`, such as file or database handles? These might prevent proper unloading if they are not closed.

Comment: I got it to work in the end.  There were some references that needed clearing, and I needed to call 'Marshal.ReleaseComObject' on a legacy COM object.  Thanks for the help @Aurora